# Update Sharepoint-List with with excel-file using power automate

Tags: excel, sharepoint, power-automate

I'm using PowerApps to modify a list (list A) in Sharepoint. Some of the data displayed in this list is from another list (list B), displayed using lookup. Every week I update list B, with data I get from a automated email. The email contain a excel spreadsheet.

I would like to automate this, but I've run into so many issues I'm not even sure it is possible anymore.
This is my flow:
[image: flow to update list B]

To my knowledge, it isn't possible to update a list directly from a excel file, unless the excel file is formatted as a table. Instead I have a empty file on my sharepoint that I update, which I later try to use as the source for updating list B.

Sadly this file is either locked by myself, or it won't recognize my table.

Any solutions to solve this problem would be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Just insert a create table step into the flow.

[image: Create table action]

So you will:

1. Receive an email with the new Excel file.
2. Save that temporarily in a secured spot.
3. Create table on the data required.
4. Use the table to update the SharePoint list.

I've done that, then I've taken the data listed and added it to a SharePoint list using sample data from a website about single board computers, here:

[image: Flow steps to add data from table to SharePoint list]